# How many itembeans can associate to a productbean - IBM WCS

Tags: websphere-commerce, wcs

In WCS7, is there any limitation to the bumber of itembeans associated to a Product bean

Comment: I've never hit a practical limit, how many are you trying to associate?

Comment: More than 150 and less than 200. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure this is possible, depending on how you view a page, this may become an issue on a PDP if you are trying to show all of the different variations, but this would be performance related, not functional, so you could do it, but  I am not sure I would recommend it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish from a business modeling perspective that you need this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard limit in how many items (SKUs) you can have for each product, but you should consider the performance implications, both for listing on the product page, but also the size of your attribute tables.

I would challenge that if you have this need, there may be better approaches, e.g. if you're trying to model an ability to customize a product (e.g. "I want 20cm of this fabric"), you can use the product attribute model (see the [PATTRIBUTE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.database.doc/database/pattribute.htm?lang=en) table) to allow shoppers to add custom attributes to the product when they add to cart.

The [Extending an SOI service with UserData](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.component-services.doc/tutorial/twvuserdatatutorial.htm?lang=en) tutorial in the V7 Knowledge Center shows an example of doing so through engraving attributes for a product.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible. considering the performance issues that can happen in PDP, if the product have to diaply all the variation details in PDP.